# How to use beaker session in bottle micro framework?

Tags: python, session, bottle, beaker

When I try to assign something to the session dictionary using beaker, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    rv = callback(*a, **ka)
  File "controllers.py", line 30, in login
    s['email'] = email
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa - - [12/Feb/2012 18:48:52] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 500 746
```

where

```
s = bottle.request.environ.get('beaker.session')
```

I follow the tutorial at the [bottle FAQ](http://bottlepy.org/page/faq).

Comment: Did you follow this `app = SessionMiddleware(app, session_opts)`?

Answer (score 6):

```
session_opts = {
    'session.type': 'file',
    'session.cookie_expires': 300,
    'session.data_dir': './data',
    'session.auto': True
}
myapp = SessionMiddleware(app, session_opts)
run(app=myapp)
```