# Bottle.py session with Beaker

Tags: python, bottle, beaker

first time questioner here.

I'm currently struggling on how to use Beaker properly using the Bottle micro-framework. Here's the problematic program:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# filename: server.py

import bottle as app
from beaker.middleware import SessionMiddleware

session_options = {
    'session.type': 'file',
    'session.data_dir': './session/',
    'session.auto': True,
}
app_middlware = SessionMiddleware(app.app(), session_options)
app_session = app.request.environ.get('beaker.session')

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    app_session = app.request.environ.get('beaker.session')
    app_session['logged_in'] = True

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    app_session = app.request.environ.get('beaker.session')
    if app_session.get('logged_in'):
        app_session['logged_in'] = False
        return 'You are logged out'
    app.redirect('/login')

@app.route('/dashboard')
def dashboard():
    app_session = app.request.environ.get('beaker.session')
    if app_session.get('logged_in'):
        return 'You are logged in'
    app.redirect('/login')

app.debug(True)
app.run(app=app_middlware, reloader=True)
```

If you noticed, I keep on calling `app_session = app.request.environ.get('beaker.session')` on every `def` block so just it will not return an error like: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment` --- it seems that Python doesn't recognize variables that is outside its function (correct me if I'm wrong).

And here are the questions:

1. What should I do to only have one instance of `app_session = app.request.environ.get('beaker.session')` so it can be available to every `def` blocks (I really need one instance since it's the same session to be checked and used).
2. If this is the only way (it's ugly though), then should I just combine all routes that requires a session just so I can achieve the single instance of `app_session`?

Something like:

```
@app.route('/<path:re:(login|dashboard|logout)\/?>')
def url(path):
    app_session = app.request.environ.get('beaker.session')
    if 'login' in path:
        app_session['logged_in'] = True
    elif 'logout' in path:
        if app_session.get('logged_in'):
            # app_session.delete() it doesn't seem to work?
            app_session['logged_in'] = False
            return 'You are logged out'
        app.redirect('/login')
    elif 'dashboard' in path:
        if app_session.get('logged_in'):
            return 'You are logged in'
        app.redirect('/login')
```

Comment: So what happens when you don't redefine `app_session` in each view function and just use the one in the global scope?

Comment: It returns an error, like this: 

    `File "server.py", line 14, in login
        app_session['logged_in'] = True
    TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment`

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248245/how-to-use-beaker-session-in-bottle-micro-framework

Comment: Sorry Blender, but I already did that before I posted the question. And also `SessionMiddleware(app, session_options)` causes an error, it should be `SessionMiddleware(app.app(), session_options)`.

Comment: I switched to Flask because of problems like this... Last attempt: try using `app_middleware.session` instead of `app.session` and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks Blender, unfortunately, it only returns a None value. However, +1 for recommending Flask, I will use it later once I finished this Bottle-based web app. ^^,

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Using `beaker` in your `bottle` application is easy.  First, set up your Bottle app:

```
import bottle
from bottle import request, route, hook
import beaker.middleware

session_opts = {
    'session.type': 'file',
    'session.data_dir': './session/',
    'session.auto': True,
}

app = beaker.middleware.SessionMiddleware(bottle.app(), session_opts)
```

And later on:

```
bottle.run(app=app)
```

With this in place, every time you receive a request, your Beaker session will be available as
`request.environ['beaker_session']`.  I usually do something like this for convenience:

```
@hook('before_request')
def setup_request():
    request.session = request.environ['beaker.session']
```

This arranges to run `setup_request` before handling any request; we're using the `bottle.request` variable (see the earlier import statement), which is a thread-local variable with information about the current request.  From this point on, I can just refer to `request.session` whenever I need it, e.g.:

```
@route('/')
def index():
    if 'something' in request.session:
       return 'It worked!'

    request.session['something'] = 1
```

Comment: Thanks larsks! the `@hook('before_request')` did the trick. :D