# Beaker session in bottle

Tags: python-2.7, wsgi, bottle, beaker

while using beaker session, i came across to use same session object along the whole application.

I came through this url: [Bottle.py session with Beaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13735333/bottle-py-session-with-beaker)

But, still i am getting 'KeyError' when i am trying to access the save session value in one function by another function.

my rest.py file looks like:

```
import bottle 
from bottle import route,default_app
from beaker.middleware import SessionMiddleware

app = bottle.default_app()
@bottle.hook('before_request')
def setup_request():
    request.session = request.environ['beaker.session']

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    request.session['uname'] = 'user'


@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    print request.session['uname']
    # expecting to print user



session_opts = {
    'session.type': 'file',
    'session.data_dir': '/tmp/',
    'session.cookie_expires': True,
}
app = SessionMiddleware(bottle.default_app(),session_opts)
```

I have mentioned the SessionMiddleware at the end as im getting errors with the help of this link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bottlepy/m0akSbWRpZg

But when i am accessing request.session in the logout function i am getting

```
'KeyError': Uname not found
```

can any one give clear example of how to adjust the code inorder to maintain same session in whole application.

Comment: Your code uses `uname` (lower case) but your error message shows `Uname` (upper case).  Typo?

Comment: sorry for that...actually the error comes with small 'uname', it's not about only 'uname' what ever value i used to declare ...when i access the same the getting the KeyError where that value is not there. @ron.rothman