# using session in bottle framework(python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, bottle

I am using bottle(python) framework to fetch data from mongodb and push to grafana.But my problem is it is fetching all the data on each request everytime.So I want to remember the timestamp or id of the last data fetched, so next time it will fetch the new data from the last timestamp or id onwards.can it be done using sessions

Answer (score 3):

Yes, You can do it using session and middleware(using encryption).

Please refer to the below URL.

[Bottle.py session with Beaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13735333/bottle-py-session-with-beaker)